# Convert longitude, latitude to cell id from s2 geometry-library python

Tags: java, python, go, geometry, s2

I am following [this tutorials](http://blog.christianperone.com/2015/08/googles-s2-geometry-on-the-sphere-cells-and-hilbert-curve/).

As explained I can convert the cell id from degrees like below

```
latlng = s2.S2LatLng.FromDegrees(-30.043800, -51.140220)
cell = s2.S2CellId.FromLatLng(latlng)
```

But I want to get the cell id from lat lng values (Not from degrees)

```
latlng = s2.S2LatLng.ToLATLANG(51.577106, 1.067254)
```

How can I do it (no need to be python)?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `java` **and** with `python`?

Comment: Because there are python and Java libraries. Answer can be on any library. Thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have latlng object, just use it in the second code line.

If not, choose needed constructor [from repository file](https://github.com/micolous/s2-geometry-library/blob/master/geometry/s2/s2latlng.h) (or documentation if exists).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find any double arguments from the library to pass (51.577106, 1.067254) ? that's why I posted the question. Sorry.

Comment: FromDegrees and FromRadians get double arguments. What are units for your  `(51.577106, 1.067254)` values?

Comment: (51.577106, 1.067254) = (latitude, longitude) from google map android user location.

Comment: Oh sorry that map lng and lat in degrees.